# Is there a cursor in R to manipulate database?

Tags: database, r, cursor

There a concept cursor  in python to manipulate database,such as:

```
cu = cx.cursor()
cu.execute('create table catalog (id integer primary key,pid integer,name varchar(10) UNIQUE）')
```

Is there a same kind of way to manipulate database in R?

Comment: Are you asking how to access a database in R?

Comment: i know we can use RODBC to access database,but my question is :,can i use sql in R  such as cu.execute('create table catalog (id integer primary key,pid integer,name varchar(10) UNIQUE）') in python.i want to use sql in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the package **sqldf** .

It has an excellent documentation here : https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/

```
library(sqldf)

# create new empty database called mydb
sqldf("attach 'mydb' as new") 

 sqldf("create table catalog (id integer not null, pid integer,name text(10) ）", dbname = "mydb")

#close 
sqldf()
```

P.S: Perhaps you should explain a little bit what you want to do. If you are already   "connected" to a database, then specify which engine  (because of different SQL statements in creating tables etc ....)